# Prompt for more context on new questions?

Tags: discussion, faq-content

Our [guidance on asking a good question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is quite generic. The context needed in Workplace SE is often different to other sites, though, and I would argue we should prompt for it, both on this page, and in early comments on new questions.

Useful and often omitted context:

- What country or at least region of the world are you in? (This often the most crucial detail.)
- What kind of organisation are you working for: corporate, government, startup, NGO?
- What size of organisation is it - corner shop, hundreds of employees, multinational?
- Are you working primarily in person or remote?
- Does the organisation span cultural boundaries? Are you all working in the same language, and is it a first language for everyone?
- Other considerations it may be useful to include: type of business (not everyone is a programmer), type of employment (voluntary / contract / salaried employee)

Related question: [Assumed Cultural Context and The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1710/assumed-cultural-context-and-the-workplace)

Comment: Interesting post, Adam. Do you have any suggested wording that you would like to pitch to be edited into that page? That way the community can vote on it and together work on a phrasing that is OK for the majority of us :)

Comment: Very sensible suggestion @DarkCygnus. I have added an answer with a suggested wording for people to vote on. Alternatives can go in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested wording change for good question guidance page:

## How do I ask a good question?

...

### Be specific

There are many workplaces all over the world with many differences. If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer, or one based on a lot of assumptions about where you work. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.

Please always include information on:

- Country or region

Consider including information on:

- What kind of organisation are you working for: corporate, government, startup, charity, non-government organisation?
- What size of organisation is it - corner shop, hundreds of employees, multinational?
- Are you working primarily in person or remote?
- Does the organisation span cultural boundaries?
- Are your team mates all working in the same language, and is it a first language for everyone?
- What sort of role are you in? (Not everyone is a programmer.)
- What type of employment is it - volunteer, contract, salaried employee, piecework?

Questions here can be on sensitive, career-altering topics. Don't feel you have to share details that would identify you or breach confidentiality. But please do share enough information that answers will be useful.