# Use Culture Indication Per Answer

Tags: feature-request

This is a follow-up to [We need flags to show our biases](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/we-need-flags-to-show-our-biases) Some of the conversation says to me that my sense of the problem is right on target.

It seems like the norm in this site is to ask localized questions and expect localized answers.

I'm proposing a different paradigm. Questions should be general or local based on the OP's preference. We do want to help the OP. If the OP expects an Indian answer then I hope someone with that culture can give a good answer. But answers from many different perspectives should be encouraged.

We would encourage answers from any culture. So a question about bullying should get multiple answers each relevant to a specific culture such as Canada or India. So we would expect to see multiple culturally diverse answers. To the OP they might seem irrelevant or wrong but hopefully would help someone from that culture.

To make this work each answer would have a box at the top stating the cultural perspective of that answer. You can be as specific or broad as you like. If you're afraid someone might disrespect your small country or just want to stay anonymous, use a very broad culture title such as Asia or Europe. Conversely if you want to highlight the narrow culture of your answer, you can be very specific e.g. hippie culture of California or Mennonite culture of Pennsylvania.

The key concept here is that questions should unapologetically attract culturally specific answers from various cultures. Each answer should be labeled at the top with the cultural perspective. Kind of like a subtitle. Then the question would be useful to many people from around the world. This could break us out of the cultural slant of the entire site. It would also greatly enhance the value of the site because readers can quickly zoom into the perspective that matters to them. At the very least it would greatly enhance the usefulness of the site.

Comment: This is close to being a duplicate of the flags question. If folks had agreed with the concept but not the implementation, this would b be useful exploration of alternative implementations. Since consensus rejected the core premise, I don't think reviving it with cosmetic differences are anything or changes any of the answers. When folks feel it's relevant, they already started the context of their answer. Normal SE interactions, including comments and voting, are sufficient to do what's needed when they are off target in a way that makes the answer not useful.

Comment: **What problem are you trying to fix?** I don't get your fascination with labels and you seem to assume that we're all horribly biased people who should check our cultural privilege. What is the "*cultural slant of the site*"? Wouldn't defining a question by a single cultures be directly opposed to your goal of attracting answers from a different cultural perspective?

Comment: @Lilienthal What I'm really looking for is a clear indication of the cultural slant of each answer. This helps me evaluate the relevance of the answer. It would really improve the value of the site.

Comment: @Lilienthal Nobody's "horribly biased" that I've noticed, but we all have a perspective. In real life, knowing a person's perspective helps me evaluate their advice. I'm less likely to dismiss it quickly if they understand me.

Comment: @Lilienthal About the "cultural slant": many have mentioned that this site is primarily (but not exclusively) western in perspective. This isn't about "cultural privilege" whatever that means. We would attract a more diverse global participation if we do something to help readers evaluate the cultural relevance of the answers.

Comment: @Lilienthal It's been a while (2013) but jmac has said the assumed context is "American office" http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1710/assumed-cultural-context-and-the-workplace

Comment: @D_Bester That has indeed been a while. It's true that many users default to a Western perspective because in my experience questions written in native speaker-level English are almost always posted by an American user. Europeans typically specify their country and less well-written questions often indicate a non-Western author. That said, the site reaction has changed since that question to incorporate the practice of leaving comments asking for clarification of the location if it's unclear, [as suggested by Rhys](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1712/25739) on that question.

Comment: In short, I don't think there is an issue that requires solving and your suggested approach causes more problems than it could potentially fix. Keep in mind that it's also never going to happen from a technical point of view.

Answer (score 4):

To use a different example, let's say you are asking a really basic programming question such as:

- How do I write a basic for loop in Python?

Would answers written in Java or C++ or JavaScript help you? It might help other people who come to the site. But would it answer *your* question?

I feel pretty strongly about this personally. Ultimately it's up to the community as a whole to decide, though.

Comment: I don't think the programming example is relevant because programming answers tend have correct answers. Correctness can be judged by asking "Does it work". WorkPlace answers are fundamentally different; the correctness is a subjective judgement, not an objective one.

Comment: Also I note that you advocate downvoting answers from the wrong culture. Others strongly disagree with you; notably @AndreiROM

Comment: @D_Bester I disagree that because answers here are often subjective there is no way to judge which are more appropriate. There are answers that are considerably _more_ correct, and those normally tend to be the ones written which address the full set of circumstances for the OP. The fact that it is perhaps harder does not mean that "any answers are valid" to any question.

Comment: @D_Bester Just because there isn't one correct answer to a question doesn't mean that there aren't answers that are definitely wrong. And sometimes those answers that are definitely wrong in one culture could be very good answers for other cultures. This could result in the highest answer being voted because "This is great, and definitely what you should do in America!", but not at all applicable to the OP who is asking about India. This would be very confusing, and possibly harmful if it isn't made clear to the OP that the answer doesn't apply to them.

Comment: In fact, sometimes an illustration is useful even if described in another language, or pseudo code. Sometimes "our culture doies it thius way" is useful as a source of ideas on  possible alternatives.  If it isn't useful, comment on why not oir downvote it... but I don't think this proposal helps predict what will or won't be useful.

Answer (score 4):

> To make this work each answer would have a box at the top stating the cultural perspective of that answer.

Setting aside the intended goal of your suggestion, this will never happen. The Stack Exchange framework is shared across many sites and this would require such a comprehensive change to the data model that we'd never get it passed, even if the entire site supported this.

Even if a solution could be hacked into the database to store this metadata, it would require redesigning the question and answer submission forms. Your suggestion can also be seen as a variation on meta tags, [which have been excised from the network](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: Bingo. If you really want to debate this, take it to the top-level Stack Exchange Meta and discuss it with the system's designers and implementors. Though as Lillienthal points  out, this has essentially been considered and rejected previously, so be sure to read that material and find some new justifications or you're likely to just get tagged as duplicate of a resolved issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This would be overly complex and confusing, only one answer is going to be accepted. It's ok for those of us who read all the answers, but not everyone does that.

Why fix something that ain't broke?

To extrapolate on this, why not allow people to use their native language as well? How messy would that get? Or have a separate workplace for different cultures and languages where all questions pertain specifically to that location?

Comment: I do think the system is broke. I don't think it would be complex or confusing. And I don't think we need to go where your extrapolations take you.